# Show multiple rows into different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have below query which shows the product listing in different rows for the same product but different sale status:

```
select distinct productname as 'Product', sale_status as 'Sold/Unsold', count(distinct i.item_number) as 'Total Items'
            from item i
            left join department d on i.item_number = d.item_number
            where d.term = 'WINTER' and d.year = '2014'
            group by productname,sale_status
            order by productname
```

It gives the output as:

```
       Product       Sold/Unsold        Total Items
        Bags            SOLD                 20
        Bags            UNSOLD              100
        Shoes           SOLD                 30
        Shoes           UNSOLD               50
```

Now I need to show the output as:

```
       Product         SOLD        UNSOLD        Total Items
        Bags            20          100             120
        Shoes           30           50              80
```

I tried using the PIVOT to achieve this task like below but I am not being able to achieve this goal. It says: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.

```
select distinct productname as 'Product', sale_status as 'Sold/Unsold', count(distinct i.item_number) as 'Total Items'
            from item i
            left join department d on i.item_number = d.item_number
            where d.term = 'WINTER' and d.year = '2014'
            group by productname,sale_status
            order by productname
            PIVOT
            (
            SUM (Total Items)
            FOR [Sold/Unsold] IN ([SOLD], [UNSOLD])
            ) as P
```

Any suggestion or any other possible way to achieve this goal?

Comment: `Total Items` is a column-name. It shouldn't have a space separation. User `"Total Items"` instead

Comment: @vkp dont you mean should be between single quotes `'`?

Comment: @Juan..single quotes for strings. this is a column.

Comment: I tried both single or double quote, it still gives me the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'."

Comment: It would need to be in square brackets...or better yet, take the space out of the derived column name. Spaces in column names just add unnecessary complexity to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your current query inside of a sub query, then pivot your subquery

```
SELECT  Product, 
    [SOLD], 
    [UNSOLD], 
    [SOLD] + [UNSOLD] AS [Total Items] 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        productname AS [Product],
        sale_status AS [Sold/Unsold],
        COUNT(DISTINCT i.item_number) AS [Total Items]
    FROM
        item i
        LEFT JOIN department d ON i.item_number = d.item_number
    WHERE
        d.term = 'WINTER'
        AND d.year = '2014'
    GROUP BY
        productname,
        sale_status
) T
PIVOT 
(
    SUM([Total Items])
    FOR [Sold/Unsold] IN ([SOLD],[UNSOLD])
) p
```